# Can't use Array in firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query why?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, angularfire2

```
const list = this.afs.collection( 'City').ref;
let queryCollection: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query & Array = list;

for (let _i = 0; _i < this.data.areaList.length; _i++) {

    if (this.data.areaList) {  
        queryCollection[_i] = queryCollection.where('areaList', '==', this.data.areaList[_i]);
    }
    console.log(this.data.areaList[_i]);
}
```

Note: can't use let only const why and how to change error ?
I wanna use let queryCollection .
[I wanna create advanced Firestore data filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R5tD.png)

Comment: what is `this.data`? add this code please

Comment: this.data. get data from input type multiple select or text

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use the same variable for your `CollectionReference` and your array of queries, which are two different things?  Consider:

```
const list = this.afs.collection( 'City').ref;
let queryCollection = [];

for (let _i = 0; _i < this.data.areaList.length; _i++) {

    if (this.data.areaList) {  
        queryCollection[_i] = list.where('areaList', '==', this.data.areaList[_i]);
    }
    console.log(this.data.areaList[_i]);
}
```

Comment: I need get specific data I have more than one ( for loop ) I try create advanced filter such as https://jo.opensooq.com/en/ajloun/real-estate-for-rent/apartments-for-rent

Comment: If you have best solution  for advanced filter tell me.

Comment: I can't get data of queryCollection .

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comments at all.  If you could add a complete example of input data and the result you want to the question, it might help.

Comment: https://scontent.famm6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/40357198_725669361103367_7407785070439694336_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=74d621b4d4587ac409bd7c7f8143f57e&oe=5C30B8D1

Comment: I need find specific data using advanced filter

Comment: Implementing an entire faceted filtering mechanism is probably too broad for a Stack Overflow question; at least it's not something I'm willing to do for you.

Comment: I was uploaded new pic above .

Comment: Can you give me example for facet filter and I will try.